# How to call a Functor template class with template function

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the code below of a unary functor which has been simplified

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class FuncT, class FuncArgT>
class UnaryFunctor
{
    FuncT func;

public:
    UnaryFunctor(FuncT const& func) : func(func) {}

    template <class ArgsT> struct result {};

    template <class F, class ArgT>
    struct result < F(ArgT) >
    {
        typedef typename std::result_of<FuncT(ArgT)>::type type;
    };

    template <class ArgT>
    typename result<UnaryFunctor(ArgT)>::type
        inline operator()(ArgT const& arg) const
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
};

template <class FuncT, class ArgT>
struct Result
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<UnaryFunctor<FuncT, ArgT>(ArgT)>::type type;
};

template <class FuncT, class ArgT>
typename Result<FuncT, ArgT>::type
inline unary_apply(FuncT const& func, ArgT const& arg)
{
    return UnaryFunctor<FuncT, ArgT>(func)(arg);
}
```

So essentially the purpose is calling a function with a value that is being passed.
Lets say we have the two simple functions below.

```
template <class T> T addValueTemplate(T const& val) { return val + 3; }
unsigned int addValue2(unsigned int const& val) { return val + 3; }
```

Calling this is fine

```
unsigned int i = 1, j;
j = unary_apply(&addValue2, i);
```

But I cant work out how to do the same thing but for the template class addValueTemplate. For example this wont compile

```
j = unary_apply(&addValueTemplate<unsigned int>, i);
```

Is there a way to do that ?
This compiles fine in GCC by the way but not in msvc

Comment: *this wont compile*, what error are you getting?

Comment: It compiles fine in GCC but not in msvc so I am nut sure what problem is

Comment: if this is compiler-specific error then (1). give the exact compiler version, (2). give the exact error message

Comment: Using MSVC 2013, Update 4 which is the latest. Compilation Error over at http://tny.cz/90479cf5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in MSVC. It thinks `&addValueTemplate<unsigned int>` is a function, not a function pointer. Use an intermediate function pointer variable:

```
unsigned int (*av)(unsigned int const&) = &addValueTemplate;
j = unary_apply(av, i);
```

Or use this to fool MSVC:

```
template <typename T>
T* identity(T* x) { return x; }

j = unary_apply(identity(&addValueTemplate<unsigned int>),i);
```

(for completeness, overload `identity` for const/non-const/rvalue references/pointers)